# System Preferences: Modification take effects instantly, how it works?

Tags: mac, defaults

Any changes on `System Preferences` app take effect instantly. However, a kill is necessary for `defaults` command to take effect. I wonder how `System Preferences` app works and is it possible to force programs/services refresh without kill like `System Preferences`?